# How to render a view programmatically and set as node field?

Tags: views, theming, 8, nodes, hooks

I am trying to render custom view and put the result as content of the node.

Here is my code

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables)
{
    if (isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->getType() == 'custom_type') {
        $reference_view = $variables['node']->field_reference_view->first();
        if (!empty($reference_view)) {
            $view_name = $reference_view->getValue()['value'];
            $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_name);
            $view->setArguments(array());
            $view->setDisplay('block');
            $view->preExecute();
            $view->execute();
            $variables['embedded_view'] = $view->buildRenderable();

        }
    }

}
```

But this code shows only debug message and when I try to get output in a twig template file it is empty

```
    {{ node.embedded_view }}
```

What is wrong with my code. How can I render a view and set it as a content of node or just node field in order to print it in a twig template file.

Answer (score 3):

Because your variable reference is incorrect. It should be:

```
{{ embedded_view }}
```

Since you added it to the $variables array as `$variables['embedded_view']`.

As an alternative you can get the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. Example on the docs page:

```
{# You can pass arguments to the view if needed. #}
  <dt>View:</dt>
  <dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}</dd>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the better way is create a [pseudo-field](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8), is easy and very simple to arrange the field in the views modes.

Why you will create 2 templates when you can use only the node template?

> Template files should only be considered when:
>
> Adding & editing regions. Making global layout changes. Customizing
>   your layout structure.

Why pseudo-field are useful?

> Pseudo-fields are great if you have some content or data that you need
>   to render together with that of a particular entity. And since you
>   don't want to be hacky and hardcode all of this inside a template or
>   preprocessor, you can use pseudo-fields to expose some control over
>   this to the UI. This means that you can use the core drag-and-drop
>   functionality to control their visibility and position relative to
>   regular entity fields.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_extra_field_info().
 */
function MY_MODULE_entity_extra_field_info() {
  $extra = [];

  $extra['node']['custom_type']['display']['pseudo_field_name'] = array(
    'label' => t('My own pseudo-field'),
    'description' => t('My pseudo-field'),
    'weight' => 100,
    'visible' => FALSE,
  );

  return $extra;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function MY_MODULE_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  // Creating the pseudo-field     
  $reference_view = $entity->field_reference_view->first();
  $view_name = $reference_view->getValue()['value'];
  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_name);

  if (is_object($view)) {
    $view->setArguments([]);
    $view->setDisplay('block');
    $view->preExecute();
    $view->execute();
    $content = $view->buildRenderable('block', $args);
  }

  $build['pseudo_field_name'] = $content;
}
```

Clean the cache and enjoy ;-)

[image]

Reference:

- [Creating pseudo-fields in Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8)
- [Drupal Theming and Site Building: 6 Best Practices](https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/drupal-theming-and-site-building-6-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you've already answered my question and suggested to use pseudo-fields, but unfortunately I didn't understand than. So basically the benefit is that you control the output of the field not inside a theme hook, but instead in a separate module ?

Comment: @HelloMufecayo You need to create a custom module and put inside the code. With this you will have an aditional field in your Content Type Manage Display tab, so you can use it as a normal field in your Views Modes. In your Manage Display tab the Link field (in each Content Type)  is a pseudo-field.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, but I am asking about benefits comparing to my approach, could you please add more info about that ?

Comment: @HelloMufecayo, read the references pages

Comment: @HelloMufecayo this is a benefit:  You use only the node template, you don't need to create another template, and you can use the field in the Manage Display, this is very easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've just implemented a module, but I can only see this field in the Manage Display tab, also I cannot enter this value for a node of the custom type, there is no such field.

Comment: @HelloMufecayo The pseudo-field is only to show elements, when you go to your node/12 page you will see the output of the field, the output is generated in MY_MODULE_node_view() so only for a test return a simple string to see the string in the node/123 page.